# Code to determine how many digits there are in a number prints the answer infinitely

Tags: python

I’m trying to create a Python program that can tell you how many digits there are in a number. For example, the input `2345` yields the output `4` digits. I tried making it a `while` loop but now it prints how many digits are in the number infinitely.

```py
interger = int(input('please type an interger and the programme will tell you how many digits it has!: '))

while interger != 0:
    if 0 < interger < 10:
        print ('1 digit')
    elif 9 < interger < 100:
        print('there are 2 digits')
    elif 99 < interger < 1000:
        print('there are 3 digits')
    elif 999 < interger < 10000:
        print('there 4 digits') 
    elif 9999 < interger < 100000:
        print('there are 5 digits')
    elif 99999 < interger < 1000000:
        print ('there are 6 digits')
    elif 999999 < interger < 10000000:
        print('there are 7 digits')
    elif 9999999 < interger < 100000000:
        print('there are 8 digits.')
        break
    elif interger == interger:
        print('that is correct')
```

Comment: `num_digits = len(str(integer))`

Comment: I'm not sure I see what the purpose of the while loop is here

Comment: The `while` loop is to allow for multiple inputs, right? Then the `input` call is in the wrong place and a break condition is missing (other than the 8-digit case, for whatever reason). You test `interger != 0` in the `while` condition, but where do you ever change `interger` in the loop? What makes you think this condition will ever be false and stop the loop? Also, `interger` is misspelled.

Comment: If the intention is to check multiple integers, the assignment to `interger` should happened *inside* the loop as well. The typical idiom is to use `while True: integer = int(input(...)); if integer == 0: break; ...`, which guarantees that you read input *at least* once, without having to duplicate the assignment code.

Answer (score 2):

Your 'while' condition is the cause of the infinite printing, as the value of interger is never changed. If you would like it to simply execute the print once, change

```
while interger!=0:
```

to

```
if interger != 0:
```

My suggestion for your script:

```
run = None

while run != 'q':
   integer = input("Enter number: ")
   print(f'There are {len(integer)} digits')
   run = input("Enter q to quit, enter any other key to do another")
```

Answer (score 0):

If not helpful for you, I will suggest another way.

```
interger= int(input('please type an interger and the programme will tell you how many digits it has!: '))

dig = 0
while(interger != 0) :
    interger /= 10
    dig += 1

print("There are " + str(dig) + " digits.")
```

How about this?

Answer (score 0):

### **Python code to tell number of digits in an input number and print answer only once**

```
interger = int(input('please type an interger and the programme will tell you how many digits it has!: '))
#to print once
print(f"given input {interger} has {len(str(interger))} digits")
```

**output**

```
please type an interger and the programme will tell you how many digits it has!: 65
given input 65 has 2 digits
```

Answer (score -1):

Leaving aside the fact that the algorithm is less than ideal, you just don't need a loop.

```
interger= int(input('please type an interger and the programme will tell you how many digits it has!: '))

if 0<=interger<10:     # zero is also 1 digit
    print ('1 digit')
elif 9<interger<100:
    print('there are 2 digits')
#etc.
```